# Shulchan Aruch HaRav Signs Omens Location?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, jewish-books, chabad

Does anyone know where the Alter Rebbe of Lubavitch speaks about halachos of signs and omens in Shulchan Aruch HaRav? I think the Rema speaks about it in Yoreh Deah 179:4, but does anyone know if the Alter Rebbe speaks about it?

Comment: http://chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/adhaz/sh

Comment: @sam right thanks for he site. I couldnt find it in the the table of contents, so I dont know where it is. Thanks for the site.

Answer (score 1):

You might be referring to [this](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh6/12/1/3.htm)
In choshen mishpat, shmiras haguf starting after the end of the 3rd sif